# Python Thread issues with passing thread object inside for loop

Tags: python, multithreading

Why is this code not giving all the list variables from the "servers" list? I think it was supposed to print all those hosts instead of it only printing the last variable in the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread
import os,sys
class InitThread(Thread):
    def  __init__(self,threadID, host):
        self.host = host
        self.threadID = threadID
        super(InitThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print host




servers=[ 'yahoo.com','google.com','10.0.0.10','10.0.0.0.11','10.0.0.12']

jobs = []
threadID = 1
for host in servers:
    t=InitThread(threadID,host)
    jobs.append(t)
    threadID += 1
for t in jobs:
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

After executing the above script I will get  the output as follows,

```
# python foo.py 
10.0.0.12
10.0.0.12
10.0.0.12
10.0.0.12
10.0.0.12
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing a class variable `host` in your `run` method, rather than the instance variable `host`. Since that variable is shared among all instances of `InitThread` and the last assignment made it the last element of the list, you will always get the last element of the list printed.

You can fix it by prepending `self`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread
import os,sys
class InitThread(Thread):
    def  __init__(self,threadID, host):
        super(InitThread, self).__init__()
        self.host = host
        self.threadID = threadID

    def run(self):
        print self.host
```